# Creating temporary view from a temporary table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view, temporary

I have a temporary table and I would like to create a temporary view over this temporary table.

Is it possible?

In following example I would like `#Top10Records` to be a view instead of a table so that I get

```
select * into #Top10Records from (select top 10 * from #MytempTable)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support this:

> Msg 4103, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   "#someView": Temporary views are not allowed.
>   Msg 4508, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables. Table names that begin with '#'
>   denote temporary tables.

Answer (score 58):

You can use a Common Table expression to do that:

```
WITH Top10Records  AS 
( 
 select top 10 * from #MytempTable
) 
SELECT * FROM Top10Records 
GO
```

Comment: +1 that's probably the most elegant workaround - good response

Comment: Of course, this only works for a single statement following the CTE. We don't know if the OP intended to use the temp view across multiple statements.

Comment: It is intended to be used multiple times as the #MytempTable will be changing always

Comment: My work around was to drop and create another #Top10Records temp table every time .

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but since you can only call Top10Records once how is this more useful than just using the raw select?

select top 10 * from #MytempTable

Comment: @IanLee you can use CTE (or multiple, chained CTEs) to divide your code so that it is clearer. You could want to make a complex query over one or multiple query results which are themselves produced by complex queries. Rather than having all querying logic mixed up, you can split it so it's easier to understand.