# SQL Add column with conditional values from another column

Tags: sql

I want to insert multiple columns that will be numerical values with multiple conditional statements into a temp table, but I'm unsure about the sequence of steps. (I'm using a temp table to test my query before actually editing the real table)

```
select * into #tempt from [dbo].[MainTable];

alter table #tempt 
  add [IsColumn] numeric,
      [IsTest] numeric,
      [ThisColumn] numeric;

select #tempt.Called,
  case
    when Called in ('Missed', 'No Answer', 'Voicemail', 'Disconnected') then 1 else 0
  end as IsColumn
from #tempt;
```

The `case when` works, but it's not actually inserting into the `#tempt`. I have the conditionals for the other new columns but I'm not sure how to get this to work correctly.
All of the other conditionals are the same format - if a specific column says "__", then enter a 1 in the new column, else, enter 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` does not change the data in tables. This looks like an use case for a temporary view but unfortunately SQL Server does not support temporary views.
So instead of first creating and filling `#tempt` with the structure and data from `[dbo].[MainTable]` then adding three columns to it and then filling them (using `update`) with calculated values better add and calculate them *within* the select list of the initial query which creates `#tempt`. You will have it all done in one go. Here is my suggestion:

```sql
select *,
  case when Called in ('Missed', 'No Answer', 'Voicemail', 'Disconnected') then 1 else 0 end as IsColumn,
  case when left(specific_column_a, 2) = '__' then 1 else 0 end as IsTest, 
  case when left(specific_column_b, 2) = '__' then 1 else 0 end as ThisColumn 
into #tempt
from [dbo].[MainTable];
```

You may see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185555/creating-temporary-view-from-a-temporary-table-in-sql-server) SO thread too.

Comment: The OP says they are only using the temp table to test their logic. They actually want to update the "MainTable" eventually, so I don't think creating the temp table differently helps them.

Comment: Well, having the same result out of the same expressions would serve the same purpose just as well. Except that it is far more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you don't understand why your `SELECT` statement is not updating your table, it's because you need to use an `UPDATE` statement.

What I think you want is:

```
UPDATE #tempt
  SET IsColumn = case
    when Called in ('Missed', 'No Answer', 'Voicemail', 'Disconnected') then 1 else 0
  end
;
```